# Solutions with powered modulus $m^s$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Suppose $(a,m)=1$, where $(,)$ denotes the gcd, and let $x_1$ denote a solution of $ax\equiv 1\pmod{m}$.  For $s=1,2,...$ let $x_s=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a}(1-ax_1)^s$.  Prove that $x_s$ is an integer and that it is a solution of $ax\equiv 1\pmod{m^s}$

To me, it is pretty clear that it is an integer.  Under modulus $m$, for example, $$x_2=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{a}(1-ax_1)^2\Rightarrow ax_2=1-(1-2ax_1+a^2x_1^2)\Rightarrow x_2=x_1(2-ax_1)$$
Since $x_1\equiv \bar{a}\pmod{m}$, where $\bar{a}$ denotes the multiplicative inverse under modulus $m$ we get 
$$x_2=\bar{a}(2-a\bar{a})\equiv\bar{a}(2-1) \equiv \bar{a}\pmod{m}\equiv x_1.$$
I can extend this argument using the binomial theorem to the same result under mod $m$. So $x_s$ must also be an integer.

Now how to show that $x_s$ is a solution under mod $m^s$.  I want to show that $ax-1=m^sk$, for some integer $k$.  I know that $ax-1\equiv a\bar{a}-1\equiv 0$ and $0=mk$ for some integer $k$.  Thus $0=(m^{s-1})mk=m^sk$  Therefore $x_s$ is a solution to $ax\equiv 1\pmod{m^s}$.

Am I off the mark here, spot on, or somewhere in between?

Comment: That it is an integer is straight Binomial Theorem, no modulus involved.

Comment: That's what I thought.  I calculated the powers of 2 and 3 and sort of gauged that.  I didn't feel like doing any sigma notation calculations and it seemed clear that it was always an integer.

Comment: @AndréNicolas, how is the rest of the solution?  I'm fairly confident it is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the Binomial Theorem, $1-(1-ax_1)^s$ is divisible by $a$.

For the rest, $1-ax_1$ is divisible by $m$, so $(1-ax_1)^s$ is divisible by $m^s$.  It follows that $ax_s\equiv 1\pmod{m^s}$.

**Remark:** Your argument for "the rest" was essentially the same as the argument of the second paragraph.

Comment: Perfect. Much more concise too.  Appreciation...